# How do you clear records for one table with multiple tables on the same form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I created a single form with multiple tables in Access 2016.
I am trying to figure out how I can use buttons to only make part of the form clear to enter a new record.

This form is going to be used in a warehouse for measurements.  It will contain 1 location with multiple aisles and then each aisle will have multiple rack systems.
When we measure the location information will not change.  The aisle will only change once all the racks are measured.

In order to do this, I will need the form to be able to create new records as I move to new racks and then change aisles after I finish all the racks.

Should this be one form with multiple subforms would that be easier than the way I am trying to do it?

I have looked at the `docmd.gotonewrecord` and also `gotorecord` but neither is working for just specific fields:

```
Private Sub btnNextUpright_Click()

    Dim ctrl As Control

    txtaisleID.SetFocus

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

        If ctrl.Tag = "upright" And TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctrl) = "Combobox" Then

        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

        End If

    Next


End Sub
```

I am expecting to be able to have a button on 3 parts of the Access form.

One will clear the bottom third, one will clear the bottom two thirds and then a final one will clear the whole form.

The following is the tables listed with keys

tblLocation
 -location (Primary Key)
 -inspectby
 -inspectdt

tblAisle
 -aisleID (Primary Key)
 -beamcnt
 -uprightcnt
 -2beam
 -4beam
 -6beam
 -8beam
 -uprwidth
 -uprhght
 -location (Foreign Key tblLocation)

tblUpright
 -uprID (Primary Key)
 -frntbck
 -sideside
 -aisleID (Foreign Key tblAisle)

tblBeam
 -beamlvl
 -bmlvlpass
 -bmlvlfail
 -bmlvlnotes
 -uprID (Foreign Key tblUpright)
 -ID (Primary Key)

[Form Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFMDh.png)

If you look at the form I am trying to write code that will add a new record to tblBeam and tblUpright when the NEXT UPRIGHT button is clicked  I tried the ADDNEW but it clears the entire form

With this, I then need to create another button NEXT AISLE that will add a new record to all tables except tblLocation

Comment: Hi! This is a vague question, and I am afraid any answers you get will mostly be guesses. Here is a starter question: How are you modeling the location/aisle/rack data in your table structure? The answer to this will drive the design of the forms and the rest of the application.

Comment: OK, your table structure looks good. You can easily base a form off of each of these tables. Now, onto your code sample. I am assuming this code is in the Aisle form. Why are you looping through the controls? Why don't you just do an `.AddNew` on the Upright form's recordset?

Comment: I guess I didn't think that would work since there is no group or anything dividing them like in vb and group controls

Comment: Access doesn't have grouping for forms (only reports). If you have relationships defined between your tables, you should look into SubDatasheets. You can probably do most of what you want using just them, with little or no code.

Comment: See reference: [Adding a Subdatasheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-subdatasheet-900d1d30-5ea2-4e47-80a7-ddcb87a53d14)

Comment: The tables are all set up with subdata sheets already.  I am trying to create a form similar because there are various people using this program.  Each location typically has 150 Aisles and each aisle has about 74 Uprights and each upright can have between 5-10 beams.  So you can see how this would get very difficult if they just worked with the tables.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't look at my reference closely enough. I didn't expect Microsoft to give such bad advice. To clarify, I *don't* recommend setting up subdatasheets for tables. Tables should just hold data. I *do* recommend setting up forms in datasheet view, and setting up subforms that are also in datasheet view, so you can create proper subdatasheets at the form level. You can then use combo boxes to set TempVars to limit the forms to a particular location in the underlying query. TempVars can also be used to automatically fill in defaults for hidden foriegn key fields. Hope this helps

Comment: *Better* reference: [Subdatasheets - How to use in subform?](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/204346-subdatasheets-how-use-subform)

Comment: kismert when you say recordset are you referring to using ADO for setting the recordset?  Currently, I have 2 types of forms set up in Access.  1 form is a single form with all the table fields on it.  The second one has one main form than a subform inside a subform inside a subform.

Comment: I almost always use plain old DAO recordsets, except on those rare occasions when ADO does something that DAO can't. Your form setup sounds good. As long as it works, and your users understand how to use it, I think you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to get the rows to clean.  Not the way I was hoping but it works for right now.  I had to resort to VB to create the groups and data forms.

Comment: Glad you got it to work